# Bash: check if a variable is declared (with declare)

Tags: bash, if-statement, conditional-statements, declare

How to check in Bash (5.x) if a variable is declared, after set for a failing command.

E.g.:

That should output `No fail`, because FAIL is not declared:

```
echo "Test" || declare -r FAIL
if [ -v FAIL ]; then echo "Fail"; else echo "No fail"; fi;
```

That should output `Fail`, because FAIL is declared:

```
some_command_not_existing || declare -r FAIL
if [ -v FAIL ]; then echo "Fail"; else echo "No fail"; fi;
```

However this is not working as expected. I also tried with `-z` but this is also not working.

I could just make FAIL=true, but I wanted to avoid an unnecessary string.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to do. What is the expected echoed message?

Comment: `-v` tests if the variable is _**set**_. I assume that means you have to set the variable to some value. You could do `FAIL=` to set it to the empty string.

Comment: @glennjackman I just updated my post to make it clearer.

Yes, I could use FAIL=, but I like to understand why it's not working with declare and check with -v. Or with something other if set means not declared but also assigned a value. There must be some possibility to check if a variable is declared but not assigned a value?

Comment: From `help test`: `-v VAR         True if the shell variable VAR is set.`. From bash manual: `A parameter is set if it has been assigned a value.`

Comment: `FAIL` isn't really declared. You've made a name read-only, so you can no longer assign to it, but there is no variable named `FAIL`, even with an empty value. `FAIL=` isn't a declaration, either; it's an assignment of an empty string to the name `FAIL`.

Comment: In short, you can't expect whatever C-based intuition you have for how a variable works to apply to other languages, including shell.

Comment: Anything wrong with `[ "${FAIL+x}" ]`?  True if `FAIL` is set, false otherwise?  And why not just use `if some_command_not_existing; then echo "No fail"; else echo "Fail"; fi;` like a normal shell program?

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, ["it doesn't work"](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Comment: Regarding "Bash: check if a variable is declared (with declare)" - are you asking a) how to tell if when a variable was declared the `declare` construct was used or b) how to use the `declare` construct to tell if a variable has been declared or not or c) something else? Why do you care about using the specific construct `declare` for whatever functionality it is you want to be able to implement?

Answer (score 0):

`declare` can tell you if a variable is declared.

First, looking at set and `-v`

```bash
$ FAIL=
$ [[ -v FAIL ]] && echo set || echo not set
set
$ unset FAIL
$ [[ -v FAIL ]] && echo set || echo not set
not set
```

This much we know.

Now, how about declared but unset variables?

```bash
$ declare -i FAIL
$ [[ -v FAIL ]] && echo set || echo not set
not set
$ declare -p FAIL && echo declared || echo not declared
declare -i FAIL
declared
$ unset FAIL
$ declare -p FAIL && echo declared || echo not declared
bash: declare: FAIL: not found
not declared
```

And, to remove the output from `declare`

```bash
$ unset FAIL
$ declare -p FAIL >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo declared || echo not declared
not declared
$ declare -i FAIL
$ declare -p FAIL >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo declared || echo not declared
declared
```

---

If you want a variable set with a non-empty variable to be OK, and any other case to be not OK, you can use `-n`

```bash
$ unset FAIL
$ [[ -n $FAIL ]] && echo ok || echo not ok
not ok
$ FAIL=
$ [[ -n $FAIL ]] && echo ok || echo not ok
not ok
$ FAIL=foo
$ [[ -n $FAIL ]] && echo ok || echo not ok
ok
```

Note the the double bracket conditional is more forgiving about unquoted variables. For single bracket conditional, quote it.

```bash
$ unset FAIL
$ [ -n $FAIL ] && echo ok || echo not ok    # oops, wrong result
ok
$ [ -n "$FAIL" ] && echo ok || echo not ok
not ok
```

Referencing an unset variable clashes with [`set -u`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Set-Builtin). For this you can use [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

```bash
$ unset FAIL
$ set -u
$ [[ -n $FAIL ]] && echo ok || echo not ok
bash: FAIL: unbound variable
$ [[ -n ${FAIL-""} ]] && echo ok || echo not ok
not ok
```

Comment: That's working, nice! But this also makes me think about whether I could simply save a variable with an empty string and test it, as this solution is not really nice either. I was hoping that there is a straight forward solution for testing something like that.